# What is the third parameter in SolidJSs createEffect function for?

Tags: javascript, solid-js

just started playing around with [SolidJS](https://www.solidjs.com/) and taking a look at the
[createEffect](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#createeffect) function.

```
export function createEffect<T>(
  fn: (v: T) => T,
  value?: T,
  options?: { name?: string }
): void;
```

I'm wondering what the third parameter is for and if I can access it somehow during the execution of the function being passed to createEffect. I do understand that the passed function is being called with the returned value of the last execution and that this value can be initialized with the second parameter, but what is the third parameter for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of Solid's functions, such as `createEffect`, `createSignal`, `createMemo` ect, have an optional name property.

It's used for debugging purposes. Packages such as [solid-debug](https://github.com/amoutonbrady/solid-debug) utilize these names.